# What happens when two locked threads (by a variable), switch one of their variable and try to access another?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, deadlock, synchronized

(I just started threads, so there is a big chance I'll be wrong)

If two threads of the same class, one of their variables gets into a synchronized method, and they switch one of their variables, and try to access another synchronized method using a switched variable. a deadlock will occur? and why?

An example of what I'm talking about: The class:

```
public class Person extends Thread{
    public Hand leftHand;
    public Hand rightHand;
    public String name;
    public Person friend;

    public Person(Hand a, Hand b, String name, Person f){
        this.leftHand = a;
        this.rightHand = b;
        this.name = name;
        this.friend = f;
    }

    public void switchHands(){
        if(leftHand.color.equals(rightHand.color)){
            Hand temp = this.rightHand;
            this.rightHand = friend.rightHand;
            friend.rightHand = temp;
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        synchronized (leftHand){
            System.out.println(this.name + " locked with " + this.leftHand);
            switchHands();
            synchronized (rightHand){
                 System.out.println(this.name + " locked with " + this.rightHand);   
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Hand{
        String color;
        public Hand(String c){ this.color = c; }  
    }
}
```

And in the main:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Hand whiteHand = new Hand("white");
    Hand blackHand = new Hand("black");
    Person one = new Person(whiteHand, whiteHand, "one", null);
    Person second = new Person(blackHand, blackHand, "second", null);
    one.friend = second;
    second.friend = one;
    one.start();
    second.start()
}
```

as you can see, the two threads (one and two), gets locked in `synchronized (leftHand)` , afterwards one of the threads at least switch hands (the right hand), and then - we try to access `synchronized (rightHand)`, and a deadlock probably occurred.

I can understand the logic, but when I switch the hands, intuitively I think I'll just copy the content of the other hand, but **I don't understand why a deadlock occurs**.

P.S I think my title is not precise enough, so an edit will be welcome.

Comment: This code doesn't even compile, currently.  Please fix it, so that it's clear what you're talking about.

Comment: Fixed it. If you will run it a few times it will eventually get into a block. In the real class there were functions on the way, so a deadlock always occurred

Comment: Re, "two threads of the same class." A thread does not belong to any class.  A thread is a thing that executes code.  The `run()` method where a thread starts executing must belong to some class because, in Java, _every_ method must belong to some class; but that does not establish any special relationship between the thread and the class.  The thread is just this thing that executes the `run()` method of whatever object you give it.

Comment: Re, "one of their variables gets into a synchronized method."  That doesn't make any sense.  Variables don't "get into" (or get out of) methods or any other places.  Static variables stay in the class where they are declared, Instance variables stay with the object in which they were created, and local variables stay in the function activation where they were created.  A variable is not a thing that can move.  But sometimes we talk about moving _values_ from one variable to another.

Comment: Also, a _thread_ can get into (i.e., "call") or get out of (i.e., "return from") a method.

Comment: Re, "...try to access another synchronized method using a switched variable..." That doesn't make sense.  You don't use a variable to access a method.  You can _pass a value_ as a _parameter_ when you _call_ a method, and the value could come from a variable.  IMO, there is a lot you could learn about how to write Java code and how to talk about Java code before you try to learn how to write multi-threaded programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think about your code as synchronizing on `leftHand` or `rightHand` because that's not what it is doing. You're really synchronizing on either `whiteHand` or `blackHand`. Your two different `Person` objects, when run, *could* look something like this:

```
Person one: synchronized whiteHand
Person two: synchronized blackHand
Person two: synchronized whiteHand
Person one: synchronized blackHand
```

Can you see how this will not work? You have not prevented the other thread from synchronizing on the inner synchronized block. It is possible for Person two to acquire the `blackHand` lock, and then wait for Person one to release the `whiteHand` lock. However, Person one won't release the already held `whiteHand` lock, because it is waiting for Person two to release the `blackHand` lock, which in turn is waiting for Person one and so on and so forth. This cyclic dependency will lead to deadlock.

The quick fix here is to simply use a lock per instance of `Person` and make `Hand` thread safe by setting the `color` to `final`.

After that, you'd need to set `name` to final and synchronize access to `friend` in order to make `Person` thread safe.